# Why do I get the error Login attempt failed please check the username and password

Tags: jquery, json, sugarcrm

I am getting same error though I am passing correct username and password also.

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 27 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title/>
    </head>
   <body>{"name":"Invalid Login","number":10,"description":"Login attempt failed please check the username and password"}</body>
</html>
```

I am giving the JSON request

```
http://sugarcrmpgsql-shiruslabs.rhcloud.com/service/v4_1/rest.php?rest_data={"user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"admin","version":"1"},"application_name":"SugarCRM REST API","name_value_list":[]}&"input_type"="JSON"&"response_type"="JSON"&"method"="login"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change user password from phpMyAdmin.

```
        var params = {
            user_auth:{
                user_name: "ENTER USERNAME",
                password: "ENTER PASSWORD",
                encryption: 'PLAIN'
            },
            application: 'RestAPI'
        }
        var json = JSON.stringify(params);

        var loginParam = jQuery.param({
            method : "login",
            input_type : "JSON",
            response_type : "JSON",
            rest_data : json
        });

        $http({
            url: BASE_URL + 'service/v4_1/rest.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: loginParam,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=UTF-8'
            },
        }).success(function(response){
            if(response.id)
            {
                console.log("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Please Enter Correct Username and Password');
            }
        }).error(function(error){
            alert('Please Enter Correct Username and Password');
        });
```